# "love" as a punctual verb

Tags: word-usage, verbs, aspect

I'm familiar with the verb "love" as a durative and stative verb. It's common to say "I love you," for example. However, I am wondering whether it's possible for "love" to be a punctual verb to express the idea that the state of loving someone or something comes into being at a particular moment. Are the following okay?

> John loved Mary when he first saw her.

> John loved Mary the first time he saw her.

> John loved the house when he saw it.

Comment: It would be inchoative rather than punctive/punctual (one hopes). Durative.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I thought inchoative verbs are a subspecies of punctual verbs. Do they differ in syntactic behavior (e.g., in terms of the (in)compatability with the present perfect)? Could they be thought of as punctual verbs with resultant states?

Comment: I've not got a supporting reference, but I've assumed inchoative verbs indicate the start of a durative state/process (eg the banana _ripened_), whereas punctive verbs are 'totally' momentary (or near enough), whether semelfactive ('one-off'; John _jabbed_ Jill with his finger) or iterative (the tap _dripped_ annoyingly). I've seen them as non-overlapping subsets. Of course, 'be born', 'die' ... cannot be seen as other than punctive though they 'lead' to 'changed states'.

Comment: _Love_ works with non-persons just fine: _I loved foie gras when I first had it. For about ten minutes, until I discovered how it was made_

Comment: @EdwinAshworth On the inchoative reading, "the banana has ripened for three days" is unacceptable, is it? This is like the punctual reading of "The glass has broken for two hours." In this respect, inchoatives and punctuals are closely related.

Comment: But changes can be gradual, of course. 'The banana has been ripening for three days' is acceptable, unlike  'The glass has been breaking for two hours.'  (Though I could probably write an acceptable durative sentence using 'has been breaking for [time expression]'. 'My voice has been breaking for the past 2 weeks.')

Comment: What about "The team has been winning for the past two months"? Is "win" a punctual verb?

Answer (score 1):

No, ***love*** does not express that. For this meaning, English has the phrase ***fall in love***:

> to be very attracted to someone and ***begin to love them***
> ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fall-in-love))

There is also the expression of ***[love at first sight](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/love-at-first-sight)***, but it uses *love* as a noun not as a verb.

Of course, *fall in love* can also be a process, instead of a moment, but the context will clarify that, like in your sentence:

> John fell in love with Mary the first time he saw her.

I have heard statements like:

> I loved her when she said that.

But that's more likely to mean *I liked the way she said that/I loved her for saying that.*

Comment: Native speakers' replies may surprise you. Let's wait and see.

Comment: FYI, the Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary has this sentence: I loved her when I first saw her.

Comment: I think 'John loved Mary _from the moment_ he first saw her' is more idiomatic.

Comment: 'John loved Mary the first time he saw her' doesn't worry me as a paraphrase of 'John fell in love with Mary the first time he saw her' provided it's in a literary setting.